# How to use trigger to prevent delete on table and update instead?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger, soft-delete

I would like to implement soft-delete in mysql using trigger and doing an update instead of delete. Then I found out that mysql doesn't have instead-of-Triggers.

So I would like to use a Before-Trigger but I couldn't find any way to abort the delete without throwing an error.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
use testdb;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `table1_before_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    call abort_delete_and_dont_raise_error();
    UPDATE table1 SET deleted_at=NOW() where id=old.id;
END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

I couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: most simple would be to REVOKE DELETE privileges on that table for all users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't abort the delete in Mysql without throwing an error. You shouldn't use the trigger of before delete to implement soft-delete mechanism. This is a wrong way. You should implement soft-delete mechanism in your application.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let's assume that I'm using another DBMS that supports instead-of-triggers: Would it actually be the right way to use an instead-of-trigger to implement it?

Comment: @Amit I don't think so. I think soft-delete mechanism should be implemented in the application.